# Count data in mysql is very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query for count data. If the data is 1000 the count process runs normally. But if the data amount to 500000 process count errorr.

How to speed up the count process in query mysql if the data is big?

This my query :

```
 $countResults = $db->SELECT()
                ->FROM( array(  'MM'=>'M_MEMBER'),
                        array(  'MEMBER_ID'      => 'MM.MEMBER_ID',
                             )
                      )
                ->WHERE('DATE(MM.UPLOAD_DATE) = CURDATE()')
                ->WHERE('SYNC_FLAG = ?','N')
                ->QUERY()->FETCHALL();

$totalCountResult =  count($countResults);
```

Comment: I find your query a little weird. Regardless, you can add indexing on SYNC_FLAG and MM.UPLOAD_DATE columns to optimize the select.

Comment: I don't see a "count" in the query.  Please provide the generated SQL.